# Hyperlinks without underline in RichTextBox on Windows 10 1803

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, richtextbox, rtf

I'm displaying RTF document in `RichTextBox` ("upgraded" to `RichEdit50W`). Keywords in the document are linked to a webpage using a syntax:

```
{\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK ""https://www.example.com/"" }}{\fldrslt{\cf1 keyword\cf0 }}}
```

I do not want to underline the keywords. Until Windows 10 version 1803 (and in all previous versions of Windows, including XP, Vista, 8), whenever a color was set on the anchor (note the `\cf1`), the anchor was not underlined.

But this no longer works in Windows 10 version 1803. I'm going to report this to Microsoft. But I'm not really sure, if I was not relying on an undocumented behavior. I can imagine that this change is actually not a bug, but rather a fix. So I wonder whether there is not a more correct way to prevent hyperlinks from being underlined.

Sample code:

```
public class ExRichText : RichTextBox
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "LoadLibraryW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryW(string path);

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            var cp = base.CreateParams;
            LoadLibraryW("MsftEdit.dll");
            cp.ClassName = "RichEdit50W";
            return cp;
        }
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ExRichText rtb = new ExRichText();
        rtb.Parent = this;
        rtb.SetBounds(10, 10, 200, 100);
        rtb.Rtf = @"{\rtf1 {\colortbl ;\red255\green0\blue0;}bar {\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK ""https://www.example.com/"" }}{\fldrslt{\cf1 link\cf0 }}} bar}";
    }
}
```

(unwanted) result on Windows 10 version 1803:

[image]

(desired) result on Windows 10 version 1706:

[image]

and the same result on Windows 7:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Windows 8 and above, you can use the [SendMessage function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx) to send the [EM_SETEDITSTYLEEX message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh768375(v=vs.85).aspx) to richedit control to disable the underlining of friendly links by specifying SES_EX_HANDLEFRIENDLYURL for the `lParam` argument and zero for the wParam` argument.

[SES_EX_HANDLEFRIENDLYURL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh768367(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Display friendly name links with the same text color and underlining as automatic links, provided that temporary formatting isn’t used or uses text autocolor (default: 0).

Even though the underlining is supposedly disabled by default, the RichTextBox control has it enabled.

Add the following to your `ExRichText` class to provide a method (UnderlineFriendlyLink) to disable the underlining.

```
private const Int32 WM_User = 0x400;
private const Int32 EM_SETEDITSTYLEEX = WM_User + 275;
private const Int32 EM_GETEDITSTYLEEX = WM_User + 276;

/// <summary>Display friendly name links with the same text color and underlining as automatic links, provided that temporary formatting isn’t used or uses text autocolor (default: 0)</summary>
private const Int32 SES_EX_HANDLEFRIENDLYURL = 0x100;

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private extern static Int32 SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam);

public static void UnderlineFriendlyLink(RichTextBox rtb, bool enabled = false)
{
    if (rtb.IsHandleCreated)
    {
        Int32 wParam = enabled ? SES_EX_HANDLEFRIENDLYURL : 0;
        Int32 lParam = SES_EX_HANDLEFRIENDLYURL; // settings mask
        Int32 res = SendMessage(new HandleRef(null, rtb.Handle), EM_SETEDITSTYLEEX, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        exRichText1.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue255;}{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.16299}\viewkind4\uc1 \pard\f0\fs29 Hello {\b{\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK ""http://www.fred.com""}}{\fldrslt{Link}}}}\f0\fs29\par\par https://www.google.com \par\par sd {{\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK ""http://www.fred.com""}}{\fldrslt{klasl}}}}\f0\fs29  wed asdasd \par\par}";
    }

    private void exRichText1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(e.LinkText);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExRichText.UnderlineFriendlyLink(exRichText1, false);
    }
}
```

Your post did not indicate how you are detecting the *clicking* of the links, but be advised that if you are relying on the `LinkClicked` event as shown in the above example that event may not fire due to a logic bug in the RichTextBox [CharRangeToString method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/RichTextBox.cs,e50e843694f23c30,references).  In particular this code fragment.

```
        //Windows bug: 64-bit windows returns a bad range for us.  VSWhidbey 504502.  
        //Putting in a hack to avoid an unhandled exception.
        if (c.cpMax > Text.Length || c.cpMax-c.cpMin <= 0) {
            return string.Empty;
        }
```

If you try the sample code, you will notice that the event fires only for the first link.  If `CharRangeToString` returns `String.Empty`, the event is not raised. This limiting condition uses the `Text.Length` property (58 for the example) that returns the *as displayed* length.  I believe that it should instead use the `TextLength` property (120 for the example).

By monitoring the control's parent for the EM_Notify message and processing the mouse click notification, it is possible to extract the link using the CharRange structure when compiling for x86 or AnyCPU(prefer 32-bit).  When running as a 64-bit assembly, the CharRange structure does return invalid values as indicated in the source code.

---

Edit: All testing was done on Windows 10 version 1706 as I will not install 1803 at this time.