# How to remove the underline from Hyperlink in generated RTF?

Tags: vba, vb6, rtf

We are trying to add a dynamic hyper link in VB.
But we need to remove the underline for the same

```
.Append("\rtf1 {\colortbl ;\red255\green0\blue0;} {\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK https://" + StoreData + " }}{\fldrslt{\cf1 " + MainHead.ToUpper + "\cf0 }}}")
```

Comment: Assuming you're using the RTF control, this might be your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50390118/hyperlinks-without-underline-in-richtextbox-on-windows-10-1803

Comment: No Hel O'Ween, that didn't work

Comment: Is the hyperlink written to worksheet? If so maybe a simple code in the lines of: Sheets(1).Range(“A1”).Font.Underline = False?

Comment: Is it VBA or VB6? Please don't tag with both